# How to get list of client certificates using java?

Tags: java, x509

i have the next code:

```
        // Load the JDK's cacerts keystore file
        String filename = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        String password = "changeit";
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

        // This class retrieves the most-trusted CAs from the keystore
        PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);

        // Get the set of trust anchors, which contain the most-trusted CA certificates
        Iterator it = params.getTrustAnchors().iterator();
        while( it.hasNext() ) {
            TrustAnchor ta = (TrustAnchor)it.next();
            // Get certificate
            X509Certificate cert = ta.getTrustedCert();
            System.out.println(cert);
        }
```

with this i have the list of trust root certifications but i want the list of the client certifications, the certifications that you can find in internet explorer.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/jcp.html#security you can read that the certificates are stored in `${user.home}/.java/deployment/security`.

All browsers manage the certificates in their specific location.